# What is $H_{3}Spin(3)$, and how is this related with the twist of framing on a 3-manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

From the [question](https://www.physicsoverflow.org/32208), Mr Ryan Thorngren said in the answer that the the framing anomaly of the gravitational Chern-Simons action

$$I(g)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{M}\mathrm{Tr}(\omega\wedge d\omega+\frac{2}{3}\omega\wedge\omega\wedge\omega)$$

i.e. it changes under a twist of framing on $M$ by $I(g)\rightarrow I(g)+2\pi s$ with $s\in\mathbb{Z}$, is related with the group $H_{3}Spin(3)=\mathbb{Z}$.

1. What is this group $H_{3}Spin(3)$?
2. Why is it isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?
3. How exactly is it related with the change of Pontryagin class under a change of framing on $M$?

They also talked about $\Omega_{3}^{fr}=\mathbb{Z}_{24}$.

1. What exactly is this $\Omega_{3}^{fr}$?

(I also posted [my question](https://www.physicsoverflow.org/41425) hoping to receive answers from physicists)

Comment: That's homology, a very basic invariant of topological spaces studied in algebraic topology. The group in the last question may be framed cobordism. That said, your questions would be better suited for other forums, like the one you alude or math stack exchange.

Comment: Both the computation of H_3(Spin(3)) and the third framed cobordism group can be found in many classical algebraic topology texts

Comment: @Tobias Shin How is $H_{3}(Spin(3))$ related with the twist of framing? Why does the gravitational Chern-Simons change by $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ under the twist of framing?

Comment: $\mathrm{Spin}(3)$ is isomorphic (as a Lie group) to $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, a simple Lie group. It is a general fact that third cohomology group of a simple Lie group is $\mathbb Z$ and the second is $0$. I am not sure about homology, but maybe this can be derived from the universal coefficient theorem.